# Create div with image and text as one link

Tags: html, css, href

So I'm trying to replicate a link button I saw when browsing the web. The div contains the href link, title for the card, link for the image and further text.  For me the only part of it with any kind of link is the title for the card.  I'm a bit stumped on what to do, any suggestions?

```
<div id="advice-card">
    <a href="tyres.html">
        <span id="title">How long do tyres last for?</span>
    </a>
    <div id="advice-card-media">
        <img src="assets/images/car-tyres.jpg" alt="Single tyre with dark background" height="240" width="240">
    </div>
    <div id="advice-card-content">
        Here we go through how long car tyres last and what to look for when buying new tyres.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could surround your whole div with an `a` ?

Comment: No need for a `<a href..`. Just set a JS onclick event listener on your container div (advice-card) that will redirect to whatever you want it to. That way anything clicked inside that div will work. You can simply use CSS to change the cursor while hovering the div as well.

Comment: @icecub if I'm trying to access internal links via this method,  do I still need to put in https://.....  or can I just use the generic file?  I'm not familiar with Javascript hence why I ask,  I've tried this - `<div id="advice-card" onclick="window.open('tyres.html','_self');">` but had no luck

Comment: @Fork I saw someone else comment this on a previous thread but then said it's not systematically correct,  is this true or ?

Comment: Yes, you can just use the internal link (they are called relative paths). It should be like: `<div onclick="window.location.href = './tyres.html'">`. Using `window.open` will actually open a new tab or window. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: @cameron.g yes, they're right. even though it works, it's not valid html

Comment: @icecub that works perfectly, now to just style the div.  Greatly appreciate that

Comment: Just add `style="cursor: pointer;"` to it and you're good to go. So your end result should be `<div id="advice-card" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.location.href = './tyres.html'">`. When you're ready, you should learn how to write separate CSS and JS files, but for now, this is fine to start.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you expect then try put any html element into  and it will work like button.

```
<div id="advice-card">
    <a href="tyres.html">
        <span id="title">How long do tyres last for?</span>
        <div id="advice-card-media">
            <img src="assets/images/car-tyres.jpg" alt="Single tyre with dark background" height="240" width="240">
        </div>
        <div id="advice-card-content">
            Here we go through how long car tyres last and what to look for when buying new tyres.
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but as mentioned before, this isn't valid html. `<a/>` isn't a block level element, while the `<div/>` inside it are. This can cause a few issues. You can work around it with css by using `display: block` or `inline-block` on the `<a/>` of course, but it's not the proper way to do it.

Comment: It is valid html markup. Its standard html patern and everybody doing like this. Don't worry about it. Many other illogical things are done routinely.